# Display a loading text/spinner until a component is fully loaded(text,images...etc) in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, spinner, loading

I searched for a solution like this but I just couldn't find it properly so I am asking this question if anyone can help.

This is a Sandbox that I made and the idea is something like this: I want to show a loading text until my component(let's say a whole website: including images, text.. etc..) is fully loaded, tried to make this with useEffect hook but the useEffect only shows the loading text until the component is mounted, and the hook does that, but there are things like images inside this component that aren't fully loaded yet, so this does not work the way I want. I would appreciate it if anyone knows a way to make this work, there is a lot of information on the web for making something like this with a setTimeout but I think this is a bit of a tricky/fake way to do it because the loading spinner should show depending on the speed of your ISP right? so for users with a better internet connection the loading text/spinner time will be shorter and for others, it will be longer.

[Link to Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/loading-rqlyg)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following function on your component :

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    console.log("do something");
  }
}
```

or controll all document's loading period using

```
switch (document.readyState) {
  case "loading":
    // The document is still loading.
    break;
  case "interactive":
    // The document has finished loading. We can now access the DOM elements.
    // But sub-resources such as scripts, images, stylesheets and frames are still loading.
   console.log('do something')
    break;
  case "complete":
    // The page is fully loaded.
    console.log("do something");
    break;
}
```

you can also use this function if you need it :

```
window.addEventListener("load", event => {
  var image = document.querySelector('img');
  var isLoaded = image.complete && image.naturalHeight !== 0;
  console.log(isLoaded);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this is something new to try :), i would try this tomorrow and tell you if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a 'loading' state that is true at first and then change it's value with the onload function.

You could use it like this:

```
<div onload={setLoading(false)}>
   <img src="..." />
   <img src="..." />
   <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Onload executes when all of it's children content has finished loading. You could read more about this at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp

Comment: I tried to do something like this before, not in a div that contains the img tag but inside the img tag, it doesn't work for me because the component is not mounted and for that reason the img never loads and the onload event is never triggered. I would try this alternative tomorrow and then tell you if this works! Thank you 